# Insert copy of existing row data as new in same table and store the new primary key with respect to old one in another table

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a table of Products with columns  ProductPKID as GUID type this product depends on another product stored in column name DependsOnProductPKID another column in same table. I want to create  copy of same row in the same table but with new ProductPKID.My problem is  DependsOnProductPKID is again a product so while creating new data I have to maintain the NewProductPKID relationship with OldProductPKID in order to update the DepensOnPKID with NewProductPKID.I have to copy bulk products. Any suggestions....

Comment: Can you show us a part of your table?

Comment: select ProductPKID ,DependentONPKID from Products